# ASP.net C# makes asynchronous call on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, asynchronous, click

I want to make asynchronous method calls on button click events in ASP.Net, C#.

On Client_Side:

```
<asp:Button ID="m_reg" runat="server" class="btn1" style="width:100px;" Text="Register" onclick="m_reg_Click" />
```

On Server_Side:

```
protected void m_reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

function m_reg_Click should be called asynchronously...

Comment: an http request is asyncronous so what do you intent?

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Rune FS , I think you did not understand my question clearly, asynchronous means interaction with server without reloading page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use UpdatePanel or [Jquery Ajax Post along with PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap button and section, which needs to be updated asynchronously, with UpdatePanel. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx),
[Tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)